# Behavior of TOP with WHERE clause . Why is this query returning a value instead of NULL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make sense of the following behavior. Consider this T-SQL query:

```sql
DECLARE @num table (n tinyint NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @num VALUES (1), (2), (3)

DECLARE @iNum tinyint

SELECT  
    TOP 1 @iNum = n
FROM
    @num
ORDER BY
    n ASC

SELECT @iNum

SELECT 
    TOP 1 @iNum  = n
FROM
    @num
WHERE
    n > @iNum
ORDER By
    n ASC
       
SELECT @iNum

SELECT 
    TOP 1 @iNum  = n
FROM
    @num
WHERE
    n > @iNum
ORDER By
    n ASC
        
SELECT @iNum

SELECT 
    TOP 1 @iNum  = n
FROM
    @num
WHERE
    n > @iNum
ORDER By
    n ASC
        
SELECT @iNum
```

I am trying to use a loop that goes through ascending integral values in a table. I ditched the loop and made explicit selects for the sake of this post, but the phenomenon is the same in both setups.

I would expect this to print/return 1,2,3, NULL. But instead get 1,2,3,3. Any idea why this is?

Comment: TSQL reference for this behavior with select and setting variables: [select-local-variable-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `@iNum` is `3` at the end because that was the last value that was *actually* assigned to the variable.

The last query that assigns a value, due to the *where* clause, returns no rows, it does not result in a row with a NULL value.

If you remove the assignment from the last query and run it, you'll see - nothing gets assigned in the last query because no rows are returned.

For additional clarity - if the variable assignment was the result of an *expression*, it would be assigned a NULL as that would be the expression's result if the query returned no rows, eg

```
set @variable = (<query>);
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks Stu . It was especially helpful that you pointed out the distinction between the explicit assignment from an _expression_ vs. inside a query. I'll go with the former pattern in this case.